# How to avoid repeating class properties when they are defined as standalone type and initialised in constructor?

Tags: typescript

Let's say you have a simple ES6 class and you'd like to extract constructor parameters into its own type to be DRY. E.g.

```js
type FooParams = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
};

export class Foo {
  public a: string;
  public b: number;
  public c: boolean;

  constructor({ a, b, c }: FooParams) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

How can I avoid repeating class properties since they as exactly the same as type?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you just want the constructor implementation to look like

```
constructor(params: FooParams) { Object.assign(this, params); }
```

where you use [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all the (own, enumerable) properties from `params` into the class instance being constructed.

Unfortunately the compiler cannot tell from this that you intend to have `Foo` to have the same properties as `FooParams`.  One way around this is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to inform the compiler that `Foo` also extends `FooParams`:

```
interface Foo extends FooParams { }
class Foo {
    constructor(params: FooParams) {
        Object.assign(this, params);
    }
}
```

Now things will work as desired:

```
const foo = new Foo({ a: "hey", b: Math.PI, c: true });
console.log(foo.a.toUpperCase()) // HEY
console.log(foo.b.toFixed(2)) // 3.14
```

The above isn't particularly type safe; declaration merging is kind of like a type assertion in that the compiler won't "check" it.  If you forget the `Object.assign()` line in the constructor, the compiler won't notice, and you'll have runtime errors.  So be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4KABBYC4J4A4FMwDED2qAKBDATlgtgM5gC8YoklYWAXGIVDgJYB2A5gNzhUQBGdLAK75eCHFx4QAxnV7oANgiwsJkAL5duEVlDEAzLFKRpUYBAA9dLACbET2PEXJg1WsFPlZCd9OTeUpVBYGHEEpKFQcAAo4XAJCOns4ogBKP0kqAHleACsEcIA6L0ImNhYoqAALJkIAGjBYx0IU1R5XSnbIQOCoMD1fMhYEAHcUdCjgajoAIkqEGGn6-jAAWSwqgowASXqZaFCkNRa3bsJURQL5VDYo-tQigoiAVThEHABhLwQolLSAej+YAAEgBRACaJyCZwuVxudwKvEeqGQTHMCGsUQATL8wACwABmAoARgALCAQK4QKA3HpBCxwkwgmAAILeUosVhsd4RHAAHgAKmZLAgbMRULl8lAAHw-dKSHAIKCCHAsdyebxyjLSKGMMI8mLJOjKGBpChanjZPKFYrsirVOoNZLHc0QTptajEIajA2OOj8tIkKVgfluSmUWCIMaYZLEMhmni0eiMTmtKjLIQiMSpgKyBRKFShzQBdU+UwWKy2Flssqc7mRXlJJoy00uckBHV9AZgL1RiZTMCzeaLMDLNYbba7Oi6w7OrpQ84IS7XW7oB7PV5iT6Eb44vGgiHt4ILpdw1eIiIotEY7H-QGE0nktRAA)

Comment: This looks interesting. However, since you mention that it is not particular recommended due to insufficient type checking, what would be a more appropriate solution? My aim is to avoid repetitively typing out properties twice since it can get tedious.

Comment: I didn't say it's not recommended, I said it's not completely type safe.  There are [a number of such type safety hazards in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness), and it's more feasible to be aware of them than it is to completely avoid them.

Comment: Got it. Let me re-phrase my question. Is there a solution to my question that is more type safe? I don't want to skip type safety for sake of writing less code. My primary concern is forgetting `Object.assign()` in constructor.

Comment: If that's an additional requirement for you to accept or even upvote an answer then it should be in the text of the question.  As far as I know there's no way to meet that extra requirement, but it depends on what you mean as "type safe".

Comment: I think no matter what you do there would be some place the compiler can't verify type safety for you.  You could refactor the non-type-safe part into the implementation of a reusable class factory (shown as `AssigningCtor` in the playground link in my answer); you could call it like `class Foo extends AssigningCtor<FooParams>(){}`. But this only helps if you have multiple classes like `class Bar extends AssigningCtor<BarParams>(){}`.  For a single class as shown in the question, forgetting to use `Object.assign()` is as likely as mis-implementing `AssigningCtor`.

Comment: I am not too proficient with TypeScript hence my question is a big vague and open to interpretation. I suppose that TS should not be equated with strongly typed languages like Java since TS is merely a superset on top of vanilla JS.